# Obout Suite Superform DateField issue

Tags: calendar, datefield, obout

I am using the Obout Suite in a website. 
I have a SuperForm control in which I have inserted some controls like BoundFields or DateFields.

The problem is that when I select a date at the DateField Calendar, the textbox associated doesn't refresh the value of the date.

I have something like:

```
<obout:SuperForm ID="SuperForm2" runat="server" AutoGenerateInsertButton ="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="false" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" AutoGenerateRows="false"                        DataKeyNames="IdDocumento" DefaultMode="Insert"  Width="525" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
   <Fields>
       <obout:BoundField DataField="DocumentType" HeaderText="Name" FieldSetID="FieldSet1" />                                
       <obout:DateField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Order Date" FieldSetID="FieldSet2" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" />
       <obout:DateField DataField="RequiredDate" HeaderText="Required Date" FieldSetID="FieldSet2" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" /> 

   </Fields>

    <FieldSets>                           
       <obout:FieldSetRow>
           <obout:FieldSet ID="FieldSet1" />
       </obout:FieldSetRow>
       <obout:FieldSetRow>
           <obout:FieldSet ID="FieldSet2" />
       </obout:FieldSetRow>           
    </FieldSets>
 </obout:SuperForm>
```

The tag prefix is:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="obout" Namespace="Obout.SuperForm" Assembly="obout_SuperForm" %>
```

The "obout_Calendar2_Net.dll" is referenced by the solution.
Am I forgotting something?

Thanks in advance.

Cartojal

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I found the solution. If you are using .net 4.0, like me.... you must to add the attribute clientIDMode="AutoID" to the section "pages" at the web.config file:

```
<pages clientIDMode="AutoID">
  ....
</pages>
```

This generate the asp.net controls ids like past versions of .net